# SQL IF EXISTS Command

Tags: php, sql, sql-update, exists

I am trying to see if a record exists in my SQL table, using the following code.

```
 if (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Logs WHERE id=$id)){
      mysql_query("UPDATE Logs SET loglevel = $loglevel WHERE id = $id;");
      mysql_close($con);
      echo "ID: ". $id . "'s new Logging Level is " . $loglevel . ".<br />";
   }
   else{
        echo "ID: ". $id . "was not in the table " . ".<br />";
    }
```

However, I keep getting this error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
>   /homepages/6/d382638756/htdocs/process.php on line 10

Line 10 is the line with the IF EXISTS in it. Can someone help me out?

Thanks,

Ashwin

Comment: You appear to be directly mixing SQL in with your PHP. This is not going to work. All SQL should be executed against the database using the chosen client library (mysql in your case)

Comment: The unexpected string is everything after `if (` - you're mixing mySQL Syntax with php...

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing SQL and PHP in a very strange way. I guess you mean something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Logs WHERE id="'.addslashes($id).'"', $con);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if ($row[0])
{

...
```

Comment: `addslashes()`, seriously? At the very least use `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: As we usually all use UTF-8 and not one of those asian character sets having valid multibyte characters whose second byte is a quote/backslash, there shouldn't be any problem with `addslashes`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are co-mingling PHP sytax with MySQL syntax.

For what you are doing, based on the example code given, you may want to look into [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).